# How to make a weighted Panel

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

Although I'm not asking for code on this one what I want to do is make a Panel that allows me to set a property called Weight to a child element of a property. The full idea is that I want a StackPanel with horizontal alignment that each child element has a weight. I want to grab my panels desired width (screen width) and then give each child the width that they need. so for instance

say I have this WeightPanel that has 14 buttons in them. My screen width is 480.
Button 1 has a weight of 2
Button 2 has a weight of 1
...
Button 13 has a weight of 1
Button 14 has a weight of 1.5

If each button had a weight of 1 then they would all get 34.2 for a width. But in this case I have a button that has a weight of 2 and another with a weight of 1.5. So button 1 would now get a width of 68.4 and button 14 would have a width of 51.4. So I'd recalculate what 1 should be 480-(68.4+51.4) = 360.2 / 12 = 30.

So buttons 2 to 13 would have a width of 30 and the other 2 would already have their width. I have the very basics to create a custom panel. The only bit of code that I need is so that I can go something like this

```
    <k:WeightedPanel>
        <Button k:WeightedPanel.Weight="2" Content="A" />
        <Button k:WeightedPanel.Weight="1" Content="A" />
        <Button k:WeightedPanel.Weight="1" Content="A" />
        <Button k:WeightedPanel.Weight="1" Content="A" />
        <Button k:WeightedPanel.Weight="1" Content="A" />
        <Button k:WeightedPanel.Weight="1" Content="A" />
        <Button k:WeightedPanel.Weight="1" Content="A" />
        <Button k:WeightedPanel.Weight="1" Content="A" />
        <Button k:WeightedPanel.Weight="1" Content="A" />
        <Button k:WeightedPanel.Weight="1" Content="A" />
        <Button k:WeightedPanel.Weight="1" Content="A" />
        <Button k:WeightedPanel.Weight="1" Content="A" />
        <Button k:WeightedPanel.Weight="1" Content="A" />
        <Button k:WeightedPanel.Weight="1.5" Content="A" />
    </k:WeightedPanel>
```

all the math and layout stuff I'll handle. I found one example on CodePlex wher a person was able to make a dependency property, but I wouldn't know how to access it. like this

```
        List<double> weights = new List<double>();
        foreach (UIElement child in this.Children)
        {
            weights.Add(child.Weight);
        }
```

Can someone please steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no `child.Weight`, because that's an [`Attached Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx).

Syntax should be:

```
var weight = WeightedPanel.GetWeight(child);
```

Though, this really sounds like a `Grid` to me.

You can achieve what you're asking for here with a simple vanilla `Grid`

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me to Attached Property I had NO clue what it was called. I want something a little more clean than the grid that you are talking about because I'm *trying* to make a OSK